# Transit Visa for US Permanent Resident travelling through Paris

Tags: new-delhi

I am Indian citizen and hold USA green card. I have travel plans to visit New Delhi, India from Chicago. I have found a few options and I would like to book Air France flight which will be from Chicago to Paris (CDG) and then from Paris (CDG) to New Delhi.

My question is whether or not I will require to have a transit visa to take my connecting flight from Paris CDG airport?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One ticket or two separate tickets ?

Comment: It will be one ticket booked through Air France. I am assuming they will issue two separate boarding passes.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a single ticket, the answer appears to be "no". As an Indian citizens you would need one, but as a US green card holder you are exempted.

https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/airport-transit-visa

You can check your specific details at
https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. Yes, it is a single ticket since it's booked through Air France. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Yes. One booking, one payment, one PNR (reservation) number.

Comment: Thanks, I would also like to clarify one thing that I will be returning via Emirates. I hope this won't make any difference. Right?

Comment: I strongly recommend putting ALL your specific details into the IATA link that I posted. This is dependent on a lot of different factors.

Comment: I think that I should be fine as per IATA.

Comment: @Curioussam returning by a different airline shouldn't be a problem. Leaving Paris on a different ticket from the one you arrived on poses a problem if you have to claim and recheck your luggage, because then you would need a regular Schengen visa (an airport transit visa does not allow you to go through the passport checkpoint, which you would need to do to retrieve and recheck your luggage). On top of that the first airline might not even let you board because they have no guarantee that the second flight will happen. You're clearly not in this situation, so there's nothing to worry about.